# Subject for sending email

Tags: java, properties, spring-el

I'm working on service for sending email to customers.
All settings like host, protocol etc, and also email sender or subject I have stored in application.properties.

In another place I have class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "email.properties")
public class EmailProperties {

private String sender;
private String subject;
```

and data from application.properties are copy to this class, and this works very well...

But what is my problem.
I would like set subject e.g:

```
email.properties.subject=Hello CUSTOMER, thank you for registered.
```

and bind CUSTOMER for concrete customer name when i send email, like:

```
Hello Tom Rich, thank you for registered.
```

So I added to class EmailProperties method:

```
String getSubjectWithCustomer(User user){
...}
```

but I have no idea how can i bind CUSTOMER for concrete user. Probably i can do something like this:

```
String getSubjectWithCustomer(User user){
  return subject.replaceAll("CUSTOMER", user.getUserName());
}
```

but i feel this is stupid solution. I would like use something better. Maybe do you have some idea? Maybe i can use SpEL for this? But i have no idea how, because everywhere i found only examples how binding XML files but not aplication.properties.

Maybe i can create some parser with using SpEL?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Spring MessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) where you can define parametrized and localized messages.

Something like:

```
public String getLocalizedSubject(Object[] params) {
    return getLocalizedSubject(params, Locale.getDefault());
}

public String getLocalizedSubject(Object[] params, Locale locale) {
    return messageSource.getMessage("subject", params, locale);
}
```

Using:

```
Object[] params = new Object[] { user.getUserName() };
getLocalizedSubject(params);
```

And define subject in the messages.properties

```
subject=Hello {0}, thank you for register.
```